# $addToSet for hashes?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

`$addToSet` seems to add to arrays only, is it possible to add a hash to a hash?

```
{
    "a"=>"1",
    "b"=>"2",
    "c"=>{"d"=>"3"}
}
```

to

```
{
    "a"=>"1",
    "b"=>"2",
    "c"=>{"d"=>"3","e"=>"4"}
}
```

And in ruby would be pref. But I'm okay with anything atm that'll help me solve this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `$addToSet` was meant to be used on arrays. You need `$set` and dot notation

```
db.collection.update(query, {$set: {'c.e': '4'}});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `$addToSet`, because a hash (i.e. a BSON object) can only have one of any given key -- they already have set semantics regarding keys (not values, however).

To update sub-objects within BSON objects, you should use `$set` as Sergio suggests.